# Is it a shameless copy/paste?

Tags: discussion

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908540/consuming-a-promise-doesnt-execute-in-then-nor-catch?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and received two answers: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908570/1675891) and [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908575/1675891).

I find it a bit suspicious that they are so similar but I don't feel confident enough to judge. Also, in case that's a copycating, how do I tell which was the original one? Both say *16 hours ago*...

Comment: Gee. Both are based on your question. How surprising that the code is almost identical to yours.

Comment: Yes,  but you can sort by time, and hover over the time and see the exact timestamp of when the answer was originally posted

Comment: There was a difference of about 20 seconds between the first two answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hover on the "xx hours ago" and see the exact time.

[image: hover]

As it is a 26 second difference only and it is not a complete copy and paste, I do not believe it is a "shameless copy and paste".